# Выписывает лекарства (не)психиатрического профиля

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> Терапевт нейролептик вам не выпишет. Она имеет право выписывать
> лекарства только (не)психиатрического профиля.

Слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Надо "только" добавить, чтобы был правильным смысл.

Comment: Надо бы еще ответ добавить...))

Comment: Только не подсказку, как водится. Интересно, что предложит сама Катя...

Comment: Я бы слитно написала.